# Error while reinstaling apache2 E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Tags: apt, apache2, dpkg

I had reinstalled apache2 because my websites were all cache and now when I try to install it I get:

```
root@vps139242:~# sudo apt-get install apache2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
apache2 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 48 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up apache2 (2.4.7-1ubuntu4.18) ...
ERROR: Config file dir.conf not properly enabled: /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dir.conf is a real file, not touching it
dpkg: error processing package apache2 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 apache2
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I've tried purging it and autoremove but still nothing I don't know what to do any help is appreciated.

Comment: Check you check disk space? Do you have any error on line before this error?

Comment: What do you mean by "because my websites were all cache"?. Also if you properly reinstall, you will most probably lose all your custom configs. Anyway, this is the command `sudo apt-get install apache2 --reinstall`.

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to reset your apache2 configuration, do the following steps.

```
# Rename your Apache2 configuration folder (just in case of).
sudo mv /etc/apache2 /etc/apache2.old

# Look up for all Apache2 package installed
dpkg -l | grep apache2

# Remove all Apache packages, usualy the following
apt remove --purge apache2 apache2-data apache2-bin

# Finally reinstall your Apache2 server
apt install apache2
```

Comment: `root@vps139242:~# sudo apt install --reinstall apache2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 48 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
E: Internal Error, No file name for apache2:amd64
`

Comment: Hum, seems to be a different error now, try `sudo dpkg --configure -a`.

Comment: `root@vps139242:~# sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up apache2 (2.4.7-1ubuntu4.18) ...
ERROR: Module mpm_event does not exist!
dpkg: error processing package apache2 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 apache2
root@vps139242:~#
`

Comment: I updated my answer :D

Comment: @olivierb2 Suggestions:  1)Proposing a more elegant line for `mv` → `sudo mv /etc/apache2{,.old}` 2)Reading  `and 48 not upgraded` does explain for me why things may have gone wrong during reinstallation attempts.

Comment: @Videonauth, thanks for your suggestion. I'm agree that your notation is more elegant, but I always try to bring clear command while the notation /etc/apache2{,.old} may be less clear for some people than providing two arguments. Regarding updates, the issue was clearly not coming from outdated package, but just a package installed partially.

Comment: Tested just now in a fully updated 14.04.5 VM and apache installs just fine. Sugesting not only removing/moving the apache2 directory, but cleaning out the package archive too (`sudo apt-get clean`) so it gets redownloaded. And before you ask how I determined the Ubuntu version just by the information given :) https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apache2/2.4.7-1ubuntu4.18

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I think your on the right track with your answer hence my up-vote.